# How to connect to nginx-container from LAN?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, network-programming, ufw

I have a docker container on my local homeserver, which is running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, using nginx.
I want to call the website, which is reachable from the homeserver itself using eihter localhost:8001 or https://192.168.178.2:8001, however i cant call it from other devices in my LAN.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"

services:
    client:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - 8001:80
        volumes:
            - ./nginx:/etc/nginx:w
```

nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  64;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {

        listen 192.168.178.2:80;

        listen 80 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/key.pem;
    }

}
```

mime.types:

```
types {
  text/html                             html htm shtml;
  text/css                              css;
  text/xml                              xml rss;
  image/gif                             gif;
  image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
  application/x-javascript              js;
  text/plain                            txt;
}
```

Futhermore there are `key.pem` and `cert.pem` as wll as `html/index.html` in the mounted `/etc/nginx` directory.

I have already configured ufw to allow connections on the correct port 8001. I even disabled ufw entirely, but this didnt resolve my issue.

I can successfully ping the homeserver on the correct port from my other machine.The website isnt reachable from other devices in the same network either.

Futhermore I checked for other connections blocking this port, i think none are. However, when running `docker exec nginx-client-1 nginx` I get the following output:

```
2023/04/05 21:16:14 [emerg] 24#24: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/04/05 21:16:14 [notice] 24#24: try again to bind() after 500ms
2023/04/05 21:16:14 [emerg] 24#24: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

This seems to be the issue, but i cant figure out where the binding to this address is configured.